# Fetch html response is not full via gatling,why?

Tags: scala-gatling

I call a http request,The reponse is html,but gatling get the response is incomplete.What should I do

I think a part of I need that is gatling supported resources.It is under the tag 'table'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may not be returning the complete response due to an error or a problem with the server-side code. In this case, you should check the server logs to see if there are any errors, and you should also check the HTTP response headers to see if there are any indications of what went wrong.

The HTTP request may be failing or being blocked by a firewall or other network security device. In this case, you should check the network logs to see if the request is being sent and received successfully, and you should also check any network security settings to ensure that the request is not being blocked.

The HTML response may not be well-formed or may be missing some elements, such as the 'table' element you mentioned. In this case, you should validate the HTML using a tool such as the W3C HTML Validator, and you should also check the HTML source to ensure that all required elements are present.

Comment: Request and response are correct on the website,only gatling received an incomplete response,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

User issue, as concluded on the [Gatling community forum](https://community.gatling.io/t/fetch-html-response-is-not-full-via-gatling/7410/4).